# how to properly overload a method in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, methods, overloading

I have a User Class which has an overloaded method "SetPassword" for populating a user credential:

```
class User
{
    ...
    [PSCredential] $Credential
    ...
    SetPassword([string] $Password){
        $UserPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
        $UserCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential (
                $this.name, $UserPassword)
        $this.Credential = $UserCredential
    }

    SetPassword(){
        $Password = Read-Host "Please Enter Password"
        $UserPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
        $UserCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential (
                $this.name, $UserPassword)
        $this.Credential = $UserCredential
    }
```

I would like to combine these two methods into one, which treats $Password as an optional parameter.  I would pass in a password for testing purposes, otherwise prompt the user for a credential.

PowerShell does not allow PARAM() in the body of a method.

Is there a better way to do this that doesn't have duplicate code as I have here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call the most specific overload from the previous ones:

```
SetPassword([string] $Password){
    $UserPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
    $UserCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential (
            $this.name, $UserPassword)
    $this.Credential = $UserCredential
}

SetPassword(){
    $Password = Read-Host "Please Enter Password"
    $this.SetPassword($Password)
}
```

---

I would probably default to using `SecureString`:

```
SetPassword([securestring] $Password){
    $UserCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential (
            $this.name, $Password)
    $this.Credential = $UserCredential
}

SetPassword([string] $Password){
    $UserPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
    $this.SetPassword($UserPassword)
}

SetPassword(){
    $Password = Read-Host "Please Enter Password" -AsSecureString
    $this.SetPassword($Password)
}
```

Comment: A suggestion: use type constructors instead of `New-Object` if you're using classes.. If you're going to use `v5` features, may as well utilize all of them for consistency and readability.  `[PSCredential]::new($this.Name, $UserPassword)`